# Error: addReview is not a function in MERN application

Tags: node.js, mern

I'm following along with a tutorial to create a movie review app on the MERN stack.

When calling my API using Insomnia, I'm getting the error "ReviewsDAO.addReview is not a function"

reviewsDAO.js:

```
import mongodb from "mongodb"
const ObjectId = mongodb.ObjectId

let reviews

export default class ReviewsDAO{

    static async injectDB(conn){
        if(reviews){
            return
        }
        try { reviews = await conn.db(process.env.MOVIEREVIEWS_NS).collection('reviews')}
        catch(e){
            console.error(`unable to establish connection handle in reviewDAO: ${e}`)
        }
    }

    static async addReview(movieId, user, review, date){
        try{
            const reviewDoc = {
                name: user.name,
                user_id: user._id,
                date: date,
                review: review,
                movie_id: ObjectId(movieId)
            }
            return await reviews.insertOne(reviewDoc)
        }
        catch(e) {
            console.error(`unable to post review ${e}`)
            return {error: e}
        }
    }
```

reviews.controller.js:

```
import ReviewsDAO from '../dao/reviewsDAO.js'

export default class ReviewsController{
   

    static async apiPostReview(req,res,next) {
        const reviewsDAO = new ReviewsDAO()
        try{
            
            const movieId = req.body.movie_id
            const review = req.body.review
            const userInfo = {
                name: req.body.name,
                _id: req.body.user_id
            }

            const date = new Date()

            const ReviewResponse = await reviewsDAO.addReview(
                movieId, 
                userInfo,
                review,
                date
            )
            res.json({status: "success"})
        }
        catch(e) {
            res.status(500).json({error: e.message})
        }
        }
```

The reviews collection is also not being created in MongoDB. But maybe that isn't supposed to happen until we create our first review.

Why isn't my function being called appropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate a ReviewsDAO object in order to call its methods.

```
const reviewsDAO = new ReviewsDAO()
```

Then you will be able to access the addReview() method

Comment: I am getting the same error after adding the initialisation... static async apiPostReview(req,res,next) {         const ReviewsDAO = new ReviewsDAO()         try{                          const movieId = req.body.movie_id             const review = req.body.review             const userInfo = {                 name: req.body.name,                 _id: req.body.user_id             }

Comment: Since you already have a const named ReviewsDAO from the import you will need to change the name of the variable you instantiated. try reviewsDao

Comment: Now instantiating reviewsDAO and calling reviewsDAO.addReview(). Same error.

Comment: can you update your question with the current code and error?

Comment: Yes, see above. Thanks

Comment: remove the static keyword from the method in the class declaration

Comment: Same error after removing static

Comment: try console logging the reviewsDAO variable

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the class method without initializing the object.

For example:

```js
class Animal{
  function sayhello(){
   console.log("Hello")
  }
}
// I can call the sayhello method by creating an object.
var dog=new Animal()
dog.sayhello() //prints "Hello"
```

But in your case, you are calling the method without creating the object.

```
Animal.sayhello() 
// It will create an error
```

So initialise the object and call the method

```
const reviewsDAO = new ReviewsDAO()
reviewDAO.addreviews()
```

The static keyword defines static methods for classes.

Static methods are called directly on the class (Car from the example above) - without creating an instance/object (mycar) of the class

So

```
const Reviewsdao= new ReviewsDAO()
ReviewsDAO().addreviews()
```

Call the method with the class name after initialising it.

Comment: I am getting the same error after adding the initialisation... `static async apiPostReview(req,res,next) {
        const ReviewsDAO = new ReviewsDAO()
        try{
            
            const movieId = req.body.movie_id
            const review = req.body.review
            const userInfo = {
                name: req.body.name,
                _id: req.body.user_id
            }`

Comment: I have changed the answer you can check it/